# How can I run an insert trigget for previous enterd data?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I write a trigger on insert but my table is not empty and have old data
I want to run my trigger for previous data.
is it possible?

Comment: No. A trigger fires on an action on a table(in your case an insert). You would need to expand on your question to elicit possible answers.

Comment: You have to write a stored procedure that performs the same set of activities that your trigger does and loops through the existing records.